# NHibernate workaround for aggregate query over a multi-column aggregate subquery

Tags: sql, nhibernate, subquery, aggregate

I'm looking for a way to emulate the following query in NHibernate...

```
select total = count(*) from (
    select userId, reportId
    from RunHistory 
    where runDate >= @d
    group by userId, reportId
) t
```

I need to get the total count of unique report runs for a user and report for use in a paged query. Problem is that HQL doesn't allow a sub-query in the from clause and I don't think it's possible with Criteria/QueryOver either. One possible solution would be to pair the two columns together and do a `count(distinct pair_report_user_ids)`, but that seems like a hack. Can you think of another way to get the total without fetching the whole sub-query result and counting the rows returned?

I think I found a [way](http://ayende.com/blog/2334/paged-data-count-with-nhibernate-the-really-easy-way), add a `count(*) over()` to the multi-column aggregate query and only select the first row!

```
select top 1 userId, reportId, total = count(*) over()
from RunHistory 
where runDate >= @d
group by userId, reportId
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's dialect specific QueryOver solution using a `count(*) over` SQL function...

```
var countOverFunction = new NoArgSQLFunction("count(*) over", NHibernateUtil.Int32, true);

UserReportRunHistoryResult dto = null;

var result = s.QueryOver<RunHistory>()
    .SelectList(list => list
        .SelectGroup(x => x.user.id).WithAlias(() => dto.userId)
        .SelectGroup(x => x.report.id).WithAlias(() => dto.reportId)
        .Select(Projections.SqlFunction(countOverFunction, NHibernateUtil.Int32)).WithAlias(() => dto.total))
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<UserReportRunHistoryResult>())
    .Take(1)
    .SingleOrDefault<UserReportRunHistoryResult>();
```